# How can i convert date to timestamp or preferably how can i add n number of days to a timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working on firebase cloud functions that i'm new to , using javascript. I have a need to add n number of days to a user who has renewed a subscription.

Here is part of the function

```
...
        var sellerRef = admin.firestore().doc('sellerProfile/'+req.query.sellerId)
        var seller = sellerRef.get().then(snapshot=>{
            const data= snapshot.data()
            var currentDate = data.subscriptionDeadline.toDate() 
            Date.prototype.addDays= function(d){
                this.setDate(this.getDate() + d);
                return this;
              };
            var newDate = currentDate.addDays(30);
            res.send(newDate)
        })
        sellerRef.update({
            subscriptionDeadline: Date.parse(newDate)
        })
...
```

In that code i got the subscription deadline of an individual then used a prototype to add 30 days as a subscription renewal. How do i convert the days back to timestamp to be able to save the new subscription deadline to firestore or better if i could add the 30 days without converting the timestamp to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore Timestamps objects don't offer any date math operations.  It will be easier if you do convert the Timestamp into a Date (or something else that lets you do math), the convert back to a Timestamp.

```
const timestamp = data.subscriptionDeadline;
const date = timestamp.toDate();
const laterDate = new Date(date.getTime() + 30*60*60*1000);
const laterTimestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(laterDate);
```

Comment: i keep getting this error on my logs `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromDate' of undefined` what could be the possible cause?

Comment: I can't see how you imported the Admin SDK, but you will need to somehow use its Timestamp type to create a new Timestamp object from the date.  What I'm showing works for me with a standard import to a variable called `admin`.

Comment: My bad, i had called it as  admin.firestore()